# Regex to remove words in curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm looking for a method to remove any substring within the braces from another substring.

For example:

- If I have the string `"The cat is {not} mine"`, I want a function that return `"The cat is mine";`
- If I have `"the glass was broken {by the dog}"`, I want a function that return `"The glass was broken "`

I have read that it would be possible using the regexp in the `replace` function but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: could you post the code you tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
var s="The {yellow} cat is {not} mine";
s.replace(/\s?\{[^}]+\}/g, ''); // "The cat is mine"
```

The regular expression allows an optional leading space `s?`, then finds the opening literal  brace `\{`, than searches multiple characters in the group `[]+` that are not a closing brace `^}` - until the literal closing curly `}`.
All that operates with the `g` global flag for multiple replaces.
 All gets replaced with `""`.

---

In the case you need to find `<[this stuff]>` delimited by `<[]>`:

```
var s = "The <[yellow]> cat is <[not]> mine";
s = s.replace(/\s*<\[[^\]\>]*\]>/g, "");
console.log( s );     // "The cat is mine"
```

Comment: use `\s` instead of ` `(empty space)

Comment: You don't need the `m` flag

Comment: ok thanks, and if a want delete string within "<[" and "]>" ??

Comment: @Ovolollo what if you try to solve it yourself (especially now when you have a template)? Don't be that lazy.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how regexp works, I have try with / ?\<\[[^}]+\]\>/g but not work

Comment: Use http://regexpal.com/ and much around until with your regex till it does what you want

Comment: @Ovolollo `[]` in regexp is a "group" or **Characters set**. so if you're looking in your string for that character literal `[` you need to escape it `\[`

Comment: OK I have retry with / ?\<\[[^\]\>]+\]\>/g and finally work, thanks

Comment: @Ovolollo *finally work*? Nonsense. In that case the right Regexp is: `s.replace(/\s*<\[[^\]\>]*\]>/g, "");`